# UITextField cannot get keyboard when mulple alertView popup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview, first-responder

In order to satisfy the need of my leader, I have to pop up multiple `alertView`s (of style `UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput` when a signal come).
But I am encountering a strange error... After multiple `alertView` popups, I lose the focus of another `textField`.

the following code:

```
if (!didDisplayAlarm && (timeInterval < -_alertStopTime) && (self.isMainViewController)) {
    didDisplayAlarm = YES; //first method

    if (_alertView) {
        [_alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO]; //second method
    }

    _alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                            message:message
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"ignore"
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"check", nil];
    _alertView.tag = kAlarmTag;

    alarmUser = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dict objectForKey:@"alarmUser"] intValue]];
    alarmPassword = nil;

    _alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
    
    UITextField *alertTextField = [_alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    alertTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
    alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    [alertTextField setPlaceholder:@"please input password"];
    [_alertView show];
}
```

I tried three method to avoid such issue:

1. set a bool var `didDisplayAlarm` to reduce the popup of `alertView`
2. use dismiss method of `alertView`
3. use textfield `resignFirstResponder` in the `alertView delegate`

My environment is IOS 6.1.3
but all doesn't work.

Comment: your question is not clear. what do you mean by "`I lose the focus of another textField`"

Comment: I just created a small test project using your code and I don't have any problems with that neither on iOS 6.1 nor on iOS 7. There are a few differences to your code, though. For example I don't have the timeInterval property as well as the check for the mainViewController. Also, I haven't implemented the UIAlertViewDelegate methods as it worked for me without them. Can you provide a screenshot showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using `resignFirstResponder` but your textfield is not identifying which one to resign. So when you are resigning the textfield then you have to make other textfield to be first responder. For example,lets say if you have multiple alertView and each contains separate textfield. So for determining the textfield just set the tag Value on textfield and on the basis of tag value resign the textfield and make other one textfield to be the first responder.

Comment: actually,I encounter this problem first so I use the third method.

Comment: also I set textfield = [alertView textFieldOfIndex:0]

Comment: No not like this, when i say tag value it means you have to set like this firstTextfield.tag=1; secondTextfield.tag=2; etc. And then on the basis of this you can identify and resign the textfield

Answer (score 0):

When you click ok/cancel in alertview you need to resign your keyboard.

to get UITextField from alertview in clickedButtonAtIndex: delegate method we have two options

Option 1 - loop the subviews of alert and get the instance of textfiled and resign it.

```
for (UIView* view in alertView.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)view;
        NSLog(@"text:[%@]", textField.text);
        break;
    }
}
```

Option 2 - you can get the textfiled instance by `[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text`. I think this can be done only if the alert style is `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`.